# How to prune neurons in neural network

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

**Context:**

Suppose we have a simple 3-layer feed-forward network. The hidden size of the first linear layer is 100000 -- `W1[input_size, 100000]` in which `input_size` is a number much smaller than `100000`. Some of neurons won't be learning any thing. I want to select and shutdown these neurons using pruning.

**Expected outcomes**

After pruning the selected neurons, we will have a smaller network with the less neurons in the first layer, say reduced to 500. And this smaller network turns out to have the same predicting capacity to the large one.

**My implementation:**

According to some criterion (some metrics applied to check weight similarities after each backpropagation update), I have cheery picked the indices of neurons I want to shut down, e.g., `[1,7,8 ...]`.

Zero out the weights represented by the indices in `W1`, `W1[:, 1, 7, 8 ...] = 0`. So that no information will be passed forward via these neurons to the next layer.

Will that be enough? Should I be manually intervening the backpropagation as well? Zero out neurons stop only computations passing forward, but for learning/updating on weights, backpropgation matters more. Since I am using `pytorch`, it will be great if illustrations are provided in `pytorch`, other frameworks like tensorflow, Keras are also fine.